# Change text on button in Swift

Tags: swift, button

Im a beginning with Swift and had done several apps where Ive changed the color of a button based on other factors.  Im not able to figure out how to change the title of a button.  I have searched other areas but what I find does not work on my system

Here is my code

```swift
choice1Button.currentTitle = storyBrain.firstStory().1
```

ChoiceButton is the button name in my IBOutlet.  currentTitle gets an error message = "currentTitle is a get only property".  The assignment Im attempting to make is a String variable found in structure storyBrain which returns 3 stings.

I also tried attributedTitle but the various choices for Normal error off in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `setTitle(_:for:)`

Example:
`choice1Button.setTitle(storyBrain.firstStory().1, for: .normal)`

See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle).